# only chrome can't resolve/access local website

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, virtual-machine

I have a few local websites running on my computer. Everything seems to work just fine but when I try to access my websites by using the Chrome browser it can't resolve or access the website, but the Firefox browser works just fine.

Error by chrome:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Could it be that the chrome browser has a different way of resolving websites? If this could be the case how can I find out for sure?

I am not using any kind of fancy proxy / firewall settings. all the sites run on port 80. The only alternative configuration I can think of is that I have a virtual network adapter configured dedicated for communicating with a virtual machine.

```
// interfaces on host
wlan0 - running DHCP (network manager)
wlan0:1 - static IP 192.168.56.111 (/etc/network/interfaces)


// interfaces on virtual machine.
eth1: NAT DHCP 
eth2: Bridged with wlan0, static 192.168.56.112
```

Pinging back and forth work by IP and site URL just works perfectly.

My setup:

```
// Host machine:
OS: Ubuntu 17.04
Chrome: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox: 54.0 (64-bit)
Running Virtualbox: Version 5.1.24 r117012

// Virtual machine (server):
OS: Debian 9
Webserver: Apache2 (PHP7.1)
```

Restarting or only using Chrome doesn't help

Any ideas and/or advice would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Deleting user profile folder may help. Path `/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome`.

Comment: This just works once, after I removed the profile folder chrome can access the site. But when I close and reopen chrome again it can't access the local site anymore. I also tried to uninstall and install chrome again but this didn't help. It seems it has something to do that is going on in the google chrome profile, but I have no idea what...

I also tried to compare a working chrome profile folder with a not working one with meld. But I don't know for what to look for...